# Bash - Regex to determine if output of ls -al is file or directory and hidden

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to find if each line of output from running `ls -al` is a file or
directory and whether or not it is hidden and count the type of each.

**EDIT:** It is imperative that I must *not* use `find`.

```
#!/bin/bash
#declare four different regex statements that match files, hidden files, directories and hidden directories (excluding . and ..)
#based on the output of each line of running ls -al
re_file='^\-[rwx\-]{9}\s[0-9]+\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s[0-9]+\s\w{3}\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s[^\.](\w|\.)*$'
re_hidden_file='^\-[rwx\-]{9}\s[0-9]+\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s[0-9]+\s\w{3}\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s\.\w(\w|\.)*$'
re_directory='^d[rwx\-]{9}\s[0-9]+\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s[0-9]+\s\w{3}\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s[^\.](\w|\.)*$'
re_hidden_directory='^d[rwx\-]{9}\s[0-9]+\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s([a-z_][a-z0-9_]{0,30})\s[0-9]+\s\w{3}\s[0-9]+\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\s\.\w(\w|\.)*$'
#declare four different counters for each type
file_count=0
hidden_file_count=0
directory_count=0
hidden_directory_count=0
#read through the output of ls -al line by line, assigning x the value of each line
ls -al $1 | while read x; do
  #test if each line matches each of the regex statements, if it does then increment the relevant counter
  if [[ $x =~ $re_file ]] ; then
    file_count+=1
  elif [[ $x =~ $re_hidden_file ]] ; then
    hidden_file_count+=1
  elif [[ $x =~ $re_directory ]] ; then
    directory_count+=1
  elif [[ $x =~ $re_hidden_directory ]] ; then
    hidden_directory_count+=1
  else
    echo "!!!"
  fi
done
total=$((file_count + hidden_file_count + directory_count + hidden_directory_count))
echo "Files found: $file_count (plus $hidden_file_count hidden)"
echo "Directories found: $directory_count (plus $hidden_directory_count hidden)"
echo "Total files and directories: $total"
```

Currently the script outputs the `!!!` from not matching any of the Regex statements for each line of `ls -al` and all of the counter variables remain at `0`. Here's an example of the input (though Bash removes the extra spaces used for padding before the Regex checks are done).

```
drwx--x--x  37 username groupname  4096 Jan  8 14:37 .
drwxr-xr-x 235 root     root       4096 Nov 15 12:16 ..
drwx------   3 username groupname  4096 Oct 27 14:35 .adobe
-rw-------   1 username groupname 14458 Dec  5 20:24 .bash_history
-rw-------   1 username groupname  2680 Sep 30 16:12 .bash_profile
-rw-------   1 username groupname  1210 Oct  7 09:40 .bashrc
drwx------  12 username groupname  4096 Dec  6 15:24 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  17 username groupname  4096 Jan  8 14:37 .config
drwx------   4 username groupname  4096 Dec  5 17:51 dir1
drwx------   2 username groupname  4096 Nov 23 12:26 dir2
...
```

I have tested the Regex on an [online Regex checker](https://regex101.com/) and they evaluate as I would like them to. I assume this is a Bash-specific problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for this simple task , why dont you use just grep

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while but got it to work.

My approach: avoid parsing the output of `ls -l`. Specially here you don't need it. Enable options so `*` in `for` loop sees hidden objects and test each object against object type (using `shopt`).

Also: `a+=1` doesn't do what you think it does. It just appends `1` at the end of the string!

```
#!/bin/bash
#declare four different regex statements that match files, hidden files, directories and hidden directories (excluding . and ..)
#based on the output of each line of running ls -al
re_hidden_file='^\..*'
#declare four different counters for each type
file_count=0
hidden_file_count=0
directory_count=0
hidden_directory_count=0

# enable hidden files/directories
shopt -s dotglob
#read through the output of ls -al line by line, assigning x the value of each line
for x in * ; do
  #test if each line matches each of the regex statements, if it does then increment the relevant counter
  if [ -d "$x" ] ; then
  if [[ "$x" =~ $re_hidden_file ]] ; then
    hidden_directory_count=$((hidden_directory_count+1))
  else
    directory_count=$((directory_count+1))
  fi
  else

  if [[ "$x" =~ $re_hidden_file ]] ; then
    hidden_file_count=$((hidden_file_count+1))
  else
    file_count=$((file_count+1))
   fi
   fi
done


total=$((file_count + hidden_file_count + directory_count + hidden_directory_count))
echo "Files found: $file_count (plus $hidden_file_count hidden)"
echo "Directories found: $directory_count (plus $hidden_directory_count hidden)"
echo "Total files and directories: $total"
```

Comment: @Jean-François_Fabre Can you explain the line `shopt -s dotglob`? Never seen that before.

Comment: with that `for` also issues hidden files/dirs.

Comment: To be clear, it alters the behavior of `*`, not `for`.

Comment: It alters globbing behavior which is used here in a `for` loop

Comment: @RobMurray: `a+=1` does what you think, if you first declare $a as integer: `declare -i a`

Answer (score 2):

You should not parse `ls` to get files. Use `find` instead with nul termination or globbing.

The problem is that `ls` produces ambiguous output for file names that are otherwise legal file names. Consider:

```
$ touch a$'\t'b
$ touch a$'\n'b
$ ls -l a*
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel  0 Jan  8 08:25 a?b
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel  0 Jan  8 08:26 a?b
```

The unprintable characters of `\t` and `\n` are replaced with `?` and render those files from `ls` ambiguous.

The same will happen with trailing spaces:

```
$ touch "a b c   "
$ touch "a b c       "
$ ls -al a\ b*
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel  0 Jan  8 08:44 a b c   
-rw-r--r--  1 andrew  wheel  0 Jan  8 08:44 a b c
```

Now consider using `find`:

```
$ find . -name "a*" -maxdepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 printf   "'%s'\n"
'./a    b'
'./a
b'
'./a b c   '
'./a b c      '
```

Or just globbing:

```
$ for fn in a*; do printf "'%s'\n" "$fn"; done
'a  b'
'a
b'
'a b c   '
'a b c      '
```

---

If you want to get total directories and total files including hidden files and directories just add that to your glob pattern:

```
file_count=0
hidden_file_count=0
regular_directory_count=0
hidden_directory_count=0

echo "=====regular files and directories:"
for fn in *; do 
    printf "'%s'\n" "$fn" 
    if [ -d "$fn" ]; then
        regular_directory_count=$((regular_directory_count+1))
    else
        file_count=$((file_count+1))
    fi      
done
echo "====hidden files and direcotries:"
for fn in .*; do 
    printf "'%s'\n" "$fn"; 
    if [ -d "$fn" ]; then
        hidden_directory_count=$((hidden_directory_count+1))
    else
        hidden_file_count=$((hidden_file_count+1))
    fi          
done

printf "Regular files: %s regular directories: %s\n" $file_count $regular_directory_count
printf "Hidden files:  %s hidden directories:  %s\n" $hidden_file_count $hidden_directory_count
tf=$((hidden_file_count+file_count))
td=$((hidden_directory_count+regular_directory_count))
printf "Total files:   %s total directories:   %s\n"  $tf $td
```

Given:

```
$ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   9 andrew  wheel   306 Jan  8 11:07 .
drwxrwxrwt  92 root    wheel  3128 Jan  8 10:58 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 andrew  wheel    68 Jan  8 11:07 .hidden dir
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel     0 Jan  8 11:26 .hidden file
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel     0 Jan  8 11:26 a?b
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel     0 Jan  8 11:26 a?b
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel     0 Jan  8 11:26 a b c   
-rw-r--r--   1 andrew  wheel     0 Jan  8 11:26 a b c       
drwxr-xr-x   2 andrew  wheel    68 Jan  8 11:07 regular dir
```

Run that and you get:

```
=====regular files and directories:
'a  b'
'a
b'
'a b c   '
'a b c       '
'regular dir'
====hidden files and direcotries:
'.'
'..'
'.hidden dir'
'.hidden file'
Regular files: 4 regular directories: 1
Hidden files:  1 hidden directories:  3
Total files:   5 total directories:   4
```

If you want to exclude `.` and `..` hidden directories you can set `GLOBIGNORE=".:.."` prior to using the `.*` glob pattern.

Comment: Unfortunately for this exercise I'm not allowed to use `find` because it would make it too easy -_- and I'm not sure I fully understand your answer :(

Comment: He created two files which `ls` shows with same name.

Comment: @Cyrus: the output is going to be piped (hence not connected to a terminal), so the two will be displayed differently (but this will of course create surprises to OP).

Comment: @Cyrus @dawg OK I see, but let's assume that this *isn't* a problem. Why do my Regex expressions not evaluate correctly? When I `echo $x` in the `while` loop in the code in the question it gives the text in the format I expect for my Regex statements.

Comment: Your `ls -la` output contains multiple blanks after nine attributes. Your regex contains only `\s`.

Comment: A very valid point, but doesn't directly answer my question. Upvoted but accepted other answer.

Comment: @RobMurray: All 4 re_* regex in your script contain at least this bug. For this reason you get `!!!`.